# Problem with successive async functions in Angular

Tags: javascript, typescript, asynchronous, rxjs, observable

getEnrolledPlayers should fetch an array of 'player' objects from the database and then pass it to the matchMaking function. However, it doesn't get passed correctly.

I tried adding observables, playing around with subscriptions

```
initializeEvent(eventId: string) {
  const enrolledPlayers: PlayerStat[] = [];
  this.getEnrolledPlayers(eventId)
    .subscribe((playerIds: string[]) => {
      for (const playerId of playerIds) {
        this.dataService.fetchSinglePlayer(playerId)
          .subscribe((playerStat: PlayerStat) => enrolledPlayers.push(playerStat));
      }
      this.matchMaking(enrolledPlayers);
    });
}
```

When I call these series of asynchronous functions, enrolledPlayers[] is calculated correctly (array of 7 elements), but it doesn't get called to the matchMaking() function correctly. I assume it's because of asynchronous runtime.

Comment: `  this.matchMaking(enrolledPlayers);` should be in your inner `subscribe()` function

Comment: @HaifengZhang you `mergeMap` would be better

Answer (score 3):

Yes. It's definitely an issue caused because of the time difference in which the inner `subscription` resolves a value.

I'd suggest using a [**`forkJoin`**](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html) and waiting on getting all the values resolved before calling `matchMaking`.

Give this a try:

```
initializeEvent(eventId: string) {
  const enrolledPlayers: PlayerStat[] = [];
  this.getEnrolledPlayers(eventId)
    .subscribe((playerIds: string[]) => {
      const playerInfos$ = playerIds.map(playerId => this.dataService.fetchSinglePlayer(playerId));
      forkJoin(...playerInfos$)
        .subscribe(enrolledPlayers: PlayerStat[] => this.matchMaking(enrolledPlayers));
    });
}
```

Or with one `subscribe`

```
initializeEvent(eventId: string) {
  const enrolledPlayers: PlayerStat[] = [];
  this.getEnrolledPlayers(eventId)
    .take(1)
    .switchMap((playerIds: string[]) => {
      const playerInfos$ = playerIds.map(playerId => this.dataService.fetchSinglePlayer(playerId).take(1));
      return forkJoin(...playerInfos$);
    })
   .tap(this.matchMaking)
    .subscribe();
}
```

Comment: single subscribe is the correct answer here. nested subscribes is an anti pattern. but you should answer this in rxjs 6+ syntax

Comment: Totally agree @bryan60.

Answer (score 2):

this is a nested subscribe anti pattern... you never nest subscribes, this is how it should look using higher order operators:

```
initializeEvent(eventId: string) {
  this.getEnrolledPlayers(eventId)
    .pipe(
      switchMap(playerIds => 
         forkJoin(playerIds.map(playerId => this.dataService.fetchSinglePlayer(playerId)))
      )
    ).subscribe((enrolledPlayers) => 
      this.matchMaking(enrolledPlayers)
    );
}
```

use switchMap to switch into a new observable and then forkJoin to run many observables in parrallel